# Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase Failed (python)

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, django-3.1, ibm-cloud-tools

I am uploading my django application to cloud foundry, here is my manifest.yml file

```
  applications:
  - name: onlinecourse
    routes:
      - route: madhavatreya.au-syd.cf.appdomain.cloud
    memory: 128M
    buildpack: python_buildpack
  - name: onlinecourse-nginx
    routes:
      - route: madhavatreya.au-syd.cf.appdomain.cloud/static
    memory: 128M
    buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

Allowed_host setting in django setting file is ['*']

How to solve this error (pillow) is not installing.
Running setup.py install for Pillow: started
Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for Pillow did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [164 lines of output]
running install

Comment: after analysis the log file WARNING: The script sqlformat is installed in '/tmp/contents1742969236/deps/0
/python/bin' which is not on PATH.
   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this war
ning, use --no-warn-script-location.
   Running setup.py install for Pillow: started
   Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'error'
   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Comment: i change the version of pillow the problem got solve